# Change multidimensional array values

Tags: php

I am trying to sanitize values, the problem is very weird to me and idk what to do.
In class `Data` I am trying to sanitize values with a function from class `Functions`, the problem is that if I run the code inside class Data to sanitize it works with no problem, but if I try to run function sanitize from class Function is not working and I can't figure it out.
This is the array I'm trying to filter:

```
function verifyData(){
  $data = [
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','<script>alert('XSS !! Solarnative ');</script>'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
  ];
}//end verifyData()
```

With the following code works perfect.

```
Class Data {
  $data array declared ablove

  foreach ($data as &$value) {
      foreach ($value as $key_1 => &$val) {
          $val = H::e($val);                
      }
  }
}//end class data
```

If I try to use function from functions it does nothing, and I can't realy understand why, this is the code:

```
class Functions {
  public static function sanitize($value){ 
    return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }//end function sanitize

  public static function sanitizeArray($data){
    foreach ($data as &$value) {
        foreach ($value as $key_1 => &$val) {
            $val = self::sanitize($val);                
        }
    }
  }//end function sanitizearray()
}//end class functions

class Data {
  $data = [
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','<script>alert('XSS !!');</script>'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
  ];
  
  Functions::sanitizeArray($data);
}
```

Comment: The function argument has to be a reference: `public static function sanitizeArray(&$data)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you just want to remove the single quotes, the main issue with you code was you were passing the 'alert('XSS!!!');' where the single quotes were closing at the place of alert before XSS by which before XSS was considered as separate values.

```
<?php
  class Functions {
    public static function sanitize($value){ 
     return htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }//end function sanitize

  public static function sanitizeArray($data){
    foreach ($data as &$value) {
        foreach ($value as $key_1 => &$val) {
            $val = self::sanitize($val);   
            echo "Getting values for sanitizing".$val."<br>";
        }
    }
  }//end function sanitizearray()
}//end class functions

function verifyData(){
  $data = [
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','<script>alert("XSS !!");</script>'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
  ];
  Functions::sanitizeArray($data);
}

verifyData();
?>
```

but if you are thinking to make it sanitize the html tags then you could go for

```
<?php
class Functions {
  public static function sanitize($value){ 
    return strip_tags($value);
  }//end function sanitize

  public static function sanitizeArray($data){
    foreach ($data as &$value) {
        foreach ($value as $key_1 => &$val) {
            $val = self::sanitize($val);   
            echo "Getting values for sanitizing".$val."<br>";
        }
    }
  }//end function sanitizearray()
}//end class functions

function verifyData(){
  $data = [
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','<script>alert("XSS !!");</script>'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
      ['test','test1','test2','test3','test4','test5'],
  ];
  Functions::sanitizeArray($data);
}

verifyData();
?>
```

I hope this would have resolved your issue.